# Google maps V2 android, the map is black

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I have a problem with google maps. When i execute my aplication at the first time the map shows me normally, but when i close and execute again the screen of the map is black.
I don't know what happens, but when i clean all the data of my application the map shown again.

First time:

[image]

Second time (when i close the application and execute again)

[image]

i'm using the virtual box with androidx86 project

Can you help me?

My code, where i set the map:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
            if (map != null) {
                try{
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
                    map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
                    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
                    map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
                    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
                    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    if(location!=null){
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        //ThreadMostraImoveisJson(latLng);
                        onLocationChanged(location);
                    }           
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.e("Erro Mapa", "Erro Setar Mapa: "+ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
    }
```

My Xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapHost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</fragment>
   <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layPesquisa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPesquisa"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPesquisa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
         android:text="" 
     />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: what if you set null to you map parameter in the onPause of the activity? does it fixes your problem?

Comment: No, i have the same problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a fresh new bug.

See on Google's issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

and

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5767

Comment: It's not way to fix the bug but removing/commenting `mapView.onPause()` solved the issue for me. (other calls seems to work fine).

Answer (score 1):

Easy workaround for this issue found on a mail thread. This solved my issue. Use relative layout and place this transparent view directly over your map fragment. Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with MapFragment showing up black. In the AndroidManifest I was using:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="false" />
```

Here setting anyDensity to false made it show up black. I set it back to true and it worked for me

Comment: Well if i don´t add <supports-screens i don´t need android:anyDensity="false"